# Passing JSON array to http_build_query

Tags: php, arrays, json, api, http

```
function callAPI($method, $url, $data)
{
    $curl = curl_init();
        
        switch ($method)
        {
        
                case "POST":
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                        if ($data)
                        {
                            echo "This is POST\n";
                            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
                        }
                        break;
        
                case "PUT":
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
                        if ($data)
                        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);                              
                    break;
  
                case "POST":
                    if ($data)
                    {       
                        print_r ($data);
                        echo http_build_query($data);
                        echo "\n";
                        echo http_build_query($data,'','&');
                        $url = sprintf("%s&%s", $url, http_build_query($data));
                        echo $url;
                    }
                
                default:
                        if ($data)  
                        break;
        }
    
    // OPTIONS:
    echo "url:".$url."\n";
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'APIKEY: 111111111111111111111',
        'Content-Type: application/json',
    ));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    // EXECUTE:
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    if(!$result){die("Connection Failure");}
    curl_close($curl);
    return $result;
}
echo "This is curl \n";
$get_data = callAPI('GET','http://localhost/AutoEZDBChecker/v1/Api.php?apicall=getMarketItems', false);
echo $get_data."\n";
//$response = json_decode($get_data, true);
//echo $response."\n";

//$errors = $response['response']['error'];
//$data = $response['response']['data'][0];
callAPI('GET','http://localhost/AutoEZDBChecker/v1/Api.php?apicall=deleteALLstoredinmarket', false);
    
callAPI('POST','http://localhost/AutoEZDBChecker/v1/Api.php?apicall=copyMarketItemsToEZDB', $get_data);
```

I tried this code which is supposed to connect to AutoEZDBChecker/v1/Api.php

deleteALLstoredinmarket and getMarketItems api calls work; getMarketItems gets the JSON array of the items of the market, deleteALLstoredinmarket deletes old DB data, and copyMarketItemsToEZDB is supposed to copy the new DB entries.

However, when I reach the POST case in my callAPI function, my program just ignores what it's supposed to do (doesn't quit, just skips over).

I tried echoing $get_data and it shows me the JSON contents properly. After it gets passed to the callAPI function as $data and echoing it, it just returns nothing, like it's empty.

**Note: Please comment-out one of the POST cases before testing**

**UPDATE: Turns out JSON failed to be decoded since I was printing a few message for debugging in the API itself and for some reason, these debugging messages where stored and interfering in the decoding of my JSON variables to associative array; Code still needs debugging**

Comment: you have 2 `case "POST":`'s

Comment: Opps! forgot to comment one of them since I was testing! But both of them fail.

Comment: Why don't you just edit your question to remove the extra case, instead of editing your question to tell people to remove the extra case???

Comment: If you're sending a POST request, you typically put data as part of the request body, not as part of the URL. If you actually need to put data in the URL, the query string starts with a question mark, not an ampersand.

Comment: And you know http_build_query takes an array as a parameter, yes?

Comment: I tried to pass it as an associative array in as the $response variable in both POST cases but no success

Comment: I tried to implement the second POST case when the first one failed it it also failed; even when I converted the JSON $get_data to associative array $response

Comment: Sorry, but I had a little time to reply, I used ampersand instead of a question mark since I already started with a question mark to indicate the apicall